# Getting add_rewrite_rule and add_rewrite_tag to work

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I am new to using **add_rewrite_rule** and **add_rewrite_tag**. I am trying to get a very basic example to work, but nothing I do seems to make it work.

**I want to access this URL (this works when entering this URl in directly):**

```
http://localhost/?author_name=rewrite
```

**Via this URL:**

```
http://localhost/name/rewrite
```

**I have the following code in functions.php:**

```
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();

add_action( 'init', 'addMyRules' );
function addMyRules(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^people/([^/]*)/?','index.php?author_name=$matches[1]','top');
    add_rewrite_tag('%author_name%','([^&]+)');
}
```

But I keep seeing a 404 page. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I simply changed it to this, and it works!

```
add_action( 'init', 'addMyRules' );
function addMyRules(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^people/([^/]*)/?','index.php?author_name=$matches[1]','top');
    add_rewrite_tag('%author_name%','([^&]+)');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Comment: you definitely do not want to flush rewrite rules on every request, it is a slow and expensive operation. rewrite rules should be flushed only when they change. please read the codex page for [`flush_rewrite_rules`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules).